# Check the data already exists in the database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to check whether the B1234ABC number plate input is already in the Firebase database? I use the web
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fN2w.png)

I want the results to be able to detect whether the text inputted on the web page can detect whether it already exists or not in the firebase database